# Meteor registration verification email not sent on production

Tags: meteor

I have tested my meteor app on dev and the verification email is sent out. But on production it is not. Could it maybe the content of smtp.js? My code is as follows:

```js
// server/smtp.js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var smtp = {
    username: 'dummy@wbs.co.za',
    password: 'hw783378hjshd',
    server:   'smtp.wbs.co.za',
    port: 25
  }

  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password)
   + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
});
```

```js
// (server-side)
Meteor.startup(function() {
  // By default, the email is sent from no-reply@meteor.com. If you wish to receive email from users asking for help with their account, be sure to set this to an email address that you can receive email at.
  Accounts.emailTemplates.from = 'NOREPLY <no-reply@meteor.com>';

  // The public name of your application. Defaults to the DNS name of the application (eg: awesome.meteor.com).
  Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = 'No Reply';

  // A Function that takes a user object and returns a String for the subject line of the email.
  Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.subject = function(user) {
    return 'Confirm Your Email Address';
  };

  // A Function that takes a user object and a url, and returns the body text for the email.
  // Note: if you need to return HTML instead, use Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html
  Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function(user, url) {
    return 'click on the following link to verify your email address: ' + url;
  };
});



// (server-side) called whenever a login is attempted
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
  if (attempt.user && attempt.user.emails && !attempt.user.emails[0].verified ) {
    console.log('email not verified');
 throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Verification email has been sent to your email address. Use the url in the email to verify yourself.');
    return false; // the login is aborted
  }
  return true;
});
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you check your junk

Comment: It was actually the content of smtp.js. I switched to using mandril - it is super fast when it comes to delivering mail. Just wish it was free though

Comment: what was wrong with smtp.js??